# Redirect user to one page if his account is not activated

Tags: php, laravel

After registration user status is by default set to 0 which means not active. Then admin needs to approve (activate) his account and then he is able to open all other routes.
How can I achieve this in Laravel? Right now I use middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::user()->userActive == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('userNotActive');
        }
    }
```

And I add it to route:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->middleware('active');
Route::get('search', 'SearchController@searchFilter')->middleware('active');
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show')->middleware('active');
```

But using this I need to add middleware to all routes manually. Is there a way I can achieve this after login to be automatically valid for all routes?

Comment: Add the condition to the auth controller?

Comment: why not use Route::group ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hardly suggest you use Route::group like

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'active'], function(){
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('search', 'SearchController@searchFilter');
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
});
```

so all you need to do is add all the page that needs to check if the user is active in that group.

Comment: But using this I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object` for `Auth::user()->userActive == 1` since user is not logged in...

Comment: All routes need authentication

Comment: then why would you get an error like that .. Trying to get property of non-object means .. the authenticated user doesn't have the field userActive .. that's all ..

Comment: How can I exclude login route?

Comment: place it outside the Route::group that has the active middleware

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. Just overwrite laravel default login method in Login Controller. Here is a working code from one of my laravel projects. No need for middleware

```
class LoginController {

    public function login(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validateLogin($request);
            // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
            // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
            // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
            if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
                $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

                return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
            }
            $credentials =['email'=>$request->email, 'password'=>$request->password];
            if($this->guard()->attempt($credentials,$request->has('remember'))){
                if(auth()->user()->active !=1){ //Account has not being activated!
                    $this->logout($request);
                    return back()
                        ->withInput()
                        ->withErrors(['email'=>'Your account is inactive. Click on the activation link sent to your account  to activate it']);

                }
                return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            }
            // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
            // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
            // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.


                $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

            return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
        }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me because I want that user to login and stay on `userNotActive` blade unless he is activated. If he tries to manually insert route in url for example `localhost:8080/library`, he must be redirected again to `userNotActive`

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of ways to do it. You can create a middleware and group routes by middleware, you can add roles and allow it by roles, you can validate input, all depends on how you want to organize or design the project. I usually create middlewares depending on my needs, alongside formrequests.

I'd probably implement @Samuel James answer on the Login method, and for all other endpoints use the form request below.
The form request would be something like:

Create a formrequest

```
php artisan make:request LoginAccess
```

and withing this LoginAccess file, I'd have a set of rules and authorization (Thinking the User model is the same you're using for Auth)

```
public function authorize(Request $request) {
 if (Auth::user()->userActive == 1) {
        return true;
 } 
 return false;
}

public function forbiddenResponse() {
  return redirect('userNotActive');
  //return response()->view('errors.403');
}

public function rules()
{
  return [
    //whatever rules you require, example here
    'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users,email,',
    'password'   => 'required|min:6|password|confirmed',
  ];
}
```

and Within your controller, you can use LoginAccess as it's validation for any method you'd require.

```
public function SomeMethodThatNeedsUserLoggedInAndValidated(LoginAccess $request)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your register method add this line to login the user directly:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // might need to add this too:
        Auth::user()->userActive = 1;

        // Authentication passed... user is logged in and active
        // @TODO : return redirect to your login start page or whatever you want to handle after login
}
```

Your middleware needs to be changed to: (as suggested by SO user @Demonyowh). This is just best practise and more easy to use.

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'active'], function(){
    Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::get('search', 'SearchController@searchFilter');
    Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');
});
```

Now when you login your user in your register method, the user will also be allowed to access all routes inside the middleware `active`

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Laravel, and this is aimed at newcomers too. Long-timers feel free to tell me why this is bad practice, as I genuinely don't know any better yet.

As at 24th August 2019 - using Laravel 5.8 - This is my personal implementation.

Assumptions made:

1. You started out using Artisan Make:Auth
2. You've added 'active' as a bool (tinyInt) to your User table and updated the relevant Models etc...
3. You're trying to prevent users from gaining access to your application when: 'active' = 0.

If this is the case, you can leave your LoginController alone.

Instead open "Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php" and replace the handle() method with:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        if(!$request->user()->active){
            // you can change 'login' to whatever you need
            return redirect('login')->with($this->auth->logout());
        }

        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Note: Auth::logout() won't work here, but it's already pulled in via the constructor at the top of the file.

```
public function __construct(Auth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }
```

So you can just use $this->auth->logout(); instead.

Thinking about it - You could very easily swap 'active' for pretty much any criteria and update this middleware the same way.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Provide the detailed answer here. Putting just a link is not sufficient.

Comment: @mentallurg Okay, added the answer detail, just didn't want to duplicate unnecessarily.